# Seeking an alternate way of referring to a "15-year ordeal"

Tags: synonyms, writing-style, greek

*Triskaidekaphobia* has become a recognized, economical alternative to *fear of the number thirteen.* Is there anything that could convey a comparably concise impression of a *decade-and-a-half* ordeal? Nothing against *fifteen-year ordeal*; I'd just like to vary the phrasing in this piece, rather than wear out that formulation.

Comment: The point about triskaidekaphobia is that it is a moderately common condition and relates to occurrences of the number thirteen in any context. Thus house numbers often skip thirteen, people avoid car registrations with thirteen in them and avoid having thirteen people around a table. Your question relates to someone suffering some ordeal specifically for a decade and a half, this is neither common nor a standard occurrence so there is no reason for a word describing it to have been coined.

Comment: I would suggest you look up "Triskaidekaphobia" in "Wiktionary, the web dictionary". You may find the etymology section there useful.

Comment: Granted, about triskaidekaphobia being common. I was wondering whether there might be some standard way, that I was not aware of, of converting Greek cardinal or ordinal numbers to English usage.

Not sure what https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/triskaidekaphobia adds.